# Better to run Visual Studio/Basic 6.0 in a Virtual PC or natively in Windows 7?

Tags: visual-studio, windows-7, vb6, virtual-machine, windows-7-x64

I developed an application 13 years ago using Visual Basic 6.0 on a computer running Windows 2000 Pro. I need to maintain the VB6 application and it also uses a 32-bit plug-in called ActiveReports.

Today, my computer is running Windows 7 Pro 64-bit.

Is it better to install and run Visual Studio/Basic 6.0 in a Virtual Machine running Windows 2000/XP on my Windows 7 host computer, or natively in Windows 7 (with installation help using [Visual Studio 6.0 Installer](http://nuke.vbcorner.net/Articles/VB60/VisualStudio6Installer/tabid/93/language/it-IT/Default.aspx))?

Comment: This isoff-topic (voting to close as opinion-based) but I'd definitely run something as old as VS 6 in a VM. There's no point in polluting the more current OS with old technology. (I have a similar setup on Windows 8.1 - I'm running VB6 in VmWare to open my very old projects when I need them.)

Comment: Don't know if this is still valid http://geekswithblogs.net/bosuch/archive/2010/11/16/installing-visual-basic-6.0-on-windows-7.aspx but I remember well that something was amiss with VB6 and Win7. I have turned to use an XP in a VM

Comment: I have Visual Studio 6 installed from the MSDN installer on Windows 10 64-bit.  No problems at all, as long as I run as Administrator.

Comment: While the VB6 IDE and compiler are certainly performant enough to be used this way there isn't much point and you lose the ability to develop and test using features of Windows introduced since the long-dead Windows XP.

Comment: I don't think that any question which asks "better" is *necessarily* opinion based. There can be clear, objective reasons why one approach is better than another, and I think the answers below support that (in this case).

Comment: As pointed out by @C-Pound Guru, Visual Studio 6 runs just fine under Win7 64-bit, given that you run it _'As Admin'_. I''ve been doing this for years. That's the only requirement. That said: keep in mind that if you want to debug interaction with other applications, you may need to start those 'As Administrator', too in order for that process to be accessible to your application / the VS IDE.

Answer (score 4):

Microsoft discourages further use of Windows XP, even on a Virtual machine, unless the machine is not connected to a network. This is due to the fact that Windows XP will no longer receive any security updates.

> After April 8, 2014, technical support for Windows XP and Windows XP Mode will no longer be available, including updates that help protect your PC. This means that if you continue to use Windows XP or use Windows XP Mode on a Windows 7 PC after support ends, your PC might become more vulnerable to security risks and viruses. Therefore, to keep your Windows 7 PC secure after April 8, 2014, **we recommend that you only use Windows XP Mode if your PC is disconnected from the Internet. Learn more about Windows XP end of support.**
>
> <sub>[source](http://windows.microsoft.com/en-us/windows7/install-and-use-windows-xp-mode-in-windows-7)</sub>

Though more recent versions of Windows have never been officially supported to run the IDE, the product team has done testing and have found that Visual Basic 6 IDE runs on Windows 7. They do recommend using the 32-bit version though:

> The Visual Basic 6.0 IDE is no longer supported as of April 8, 2008. However, Custom Support Agreements may be available from Microsoft. Additionally, both the **Windows and Visual Basic teams have tested Visual Basic 6.0 IDE on Windows Vista, Windows 7, Windows Server 2008, Windows 8  and Windows 8.1** to understand and mitigate (if appropriate) compatibility issues on 32-bit versions of Windows. This announcement does not change the support policy for the IDE.
>
> <sub>[source](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/vstudio/ms788708)</sub>

You may run into issues with 3rd party components that have not been tested or updated to work properly with Windows 7 or newer. This is true both at development and at runtime.

Especially the enhanced security features, like User Account Control and tightened security settings on COM components may cause significant problems.

This is true for both the IDE and the runtime components.

Comment: Actually when Vista came out VB6 was the only officially supported Microsoft development tool.

Comment: @bob77 not sure what you mean by that comment.

Comment: I include Vista as one of "the more recent versions" of Windows, and VB6 was clearly supported there since at first it was the *only* thing from Microsoft that did work there.

Comment: @bob77 the runtime was supported, but the idea not. Visual Studio. NET and 2005 were

Comment: The VB6 IDE was indeed supported on Vista.  No version of VS.Net was until Vista SP1 and VS 2005 SP1.

Comment: Vista never officially supported the Visual Basic 6 IDE, only the runtime.

Comment: Sorry but you are wrong, which was the very point of my first comment here.  This was even controversial at the time, prompting much whinging from .Net fans.

Comment: Check the kb article. Runtime: supported. IDE: only on support contract. Same for Vista as for Windows 7. The controversy was as far a single remember that the runtime was supported, but not the IDE. Which is strange if you think about it, but how it played out. Back then you could still develop on XP when it and VB6 IDE was still supported. Regardless, Vista is also running out of mainstream support, so windows 7 or higher really is the only option.

Comment: No, you are wrong.  Just give it up.  VB6 IDE support dropped on all platforms as of 2008, that includes XP.  The controversy was that when Vista was released no version of VS.Net was supported even though VB6 most certainly was.

Answer (score 1):

As someone who develops little fun apps and some work related tooling in VB6 (more of an interest/hobby, than anything else),  my opinion is that it's perfectly fine to run in Win7 x64.

- I find it more convenient to run it on my main desktop than in a VM.
- I've also installed VB6 on a W2k3 VM as some more obscure bugs (often around MDAC) can't be fully tested/circumvented in Win7.
- I always run the IDE As Administrator to avoid some other niggles

Answer (score 0):

It is better to use the VB6 programming IDE natively, not in a VM,

The VB6 IDE runs fine in Windows 7,8 or 10.

You can use this installer to install VB6  [Visual Studio 6.0 Installer wizard](http://nuke.vbcorner.net/)